# Folder New Columns doesn't appear to all users

Tags: windows

When I add new column, such as the Date created, to my shared folder the new column can't be seen by other users.

How can I fix this? The new column should be there because of the fact that it is a shared folder, shouldn't it?

Comment: The columns you choose to view are a personal customization to your account. Other users get to/have to decide which columns they see.  Are you the administrator of their computers?